# Conditionally bind readonly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This code is almost correct.  I have to click the button "make server set" and then go into the textarea > make a change > tab out.  Then the readonly takes effect.  How can I fix this code so that readonly takes effect immediately after I click the button?  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hzd8/6/)

HTML

```
<textarea readOnly="true" data-bind="value: text, readOnly: viewModel.text.isServerSet"  rows="5"  cols="20"></textarea> 

<input id="makeServerSet" type="button" value="Make server set" id="makeServerSet" />
```

JavaScript

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.readOnly = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            console.log('element: ' + element);
            console.log('made readonly: ' + value);
            element.setAttribute("readOnly", true); 
        }  else {
            console.log('removed readonly');
            element.removeAttribute("readOnly");
        }  
    }  
}

ko.extenders.isServerSet = function (target, value) {
            console.log('is server set...' + value);
            target.isServerSet = ko.observable(value);
            return target;
        };

var viewModel = {
    text: ko.observable("test").extend({
                isServerSet: false
            }),
    isServerSet: ko.observable('')
}; 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$('#makeServerSet').click(function() {
    viewModel.text.isServerSet = true;
    console.log('made server set');
});
```

Comment: `viewModel.text.isServerSet = true;` should be  `viewModel.text.isServerSet(true);` http://jsfiddle.net/94hYr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, set your `isServerSet` with this

`viewModel.text.isServerSet(true);`  (because it is an observable)

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2v5B/)